# Quick way to enumerate all hardlinks in python3

Tags: python-3.x, hardlink

Is there a quick way/function to enum all hardlinks of a file? Something that directly gives me the paths of all hardlinks to a given file? On windows if that matters any.

I know about `os.stat("foo.txt").st_nlink` and about `os.path.samefile(path1, path2)`.

Using these I can probably bodge together something to enumerate all hardlinks of a given file. Welcome to implementation suggestions tho.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, enumeration of hardlinks to any given file is facilitated by the [FindFirstFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilenamew), [FindNextFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilenamew), and [FindClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findclose) trio. Fortunately, [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) wraps these for us in a single call:

```py
import win32file

hardlinks = win32file.FindFileNames(r'path\as\string')
```

Less fortunately, `FindFileNames()` only accepts string input and leaves a trailing null on each path returned (bug reported [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1511)). We can easily make up for this and return more helpful `pathlib.Path` objects while we're at it:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, List

from win32file import FindFileNames


def enumerate_hardlinks(path: Union[bytes, str, Path]) -> List[Path]:

    def strip_null(p):
        return p[:-1] if p.endswith('\x00') else p

    # Convert possible path representations to a string.
    path = os.fsdecode(os.fspath(path))

    return [Path(strip_null(n)) for n in FindFileNames(path)]
```

To verify output, you can also enumerate all hardlinks to a file using [fsutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil) from both Windows CMD and PowerShell:

```
>fsutil hardlink list C:\Users\name\1st
\Users\name\1st
\Users\name\2nd
\Users\name\3rd
```

Where `1st`, `2nd`, & `3rd` are all hardlinks to the same file.

(Tested using Python 3.8 and pywin32 v227)

Comment: It seems that the bug has been resolved, `win32file.FindFileNames(r'path\as\string')` works seamlessly.